# The NetTopologySuit library gives very different results compared to the SqlGeography library

Tags: c#, sql-server, nettopologysuite

**Update:**

I changed the polygon as suggested, and I now get a LineString instead of a MultiLine string, but the difference in coordinates are still the same:

I'm comparing two libraries for working with spatial data, but they are giving me quite different results for the same input.

Here is a test using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types library

```
    // Line from New York to Paris
    SqlGeography line = SqlGeography.STLineFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars("LINESTRING(-73.935242 40.730610, 2.349014 48.864716)"), 4326);
    
    // Polygon in the Atlantic
    SqlGeography polygon = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars("POLYGON((-40 60,  -40 30, -20 30, -20 60, -40 60))"), 4326);

        SqlGeography intersection = line.STIntersection(polygon);
```

> {LINESTRING (-19.99999999999997 52.21038270929611, -39.99999999999993
> 51.451383473748834)}

Here is a test with the NetTopologySuite:

```
var polygonText = "POLYGON((-40 60,  -40 30, -20 30, -20 60, -40 60))";
string lineText = "LINESTRING(-73.935242 40.730610, 2.349014 48.864716)";
var rdr = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKTReader();
var geometryPolygon = rdr.Read(polygonText);
var geometryLine = rdr.Read(lineText);

var polygon =  _geometryFactory.CreatePolygon(geometryPolygon.Coordinates);
var line = _geometryFactory.CreateLineString(geometryLine.Coordinates);
    

    var intersects = line.Intersection(polygon);
```

> {LINESTRING (-40 44.34908739019244, -20 46.48166531033365)}

Any idea why there is such a large difference in the result?

Comment: What makes you believe it would use coordinates in a different order when these are both meant to be working with a *standard* representation? The quickest way to check which way around the coordinates are meant to be is to use one that exceeds 90° in one position and then the other and see which way around it complains about it.

Comment: SqlGeography  does indeed give an error if I change the second value to be more than 90 `Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.`
NetTopologySuite  does not give me any errors

Comment: With NetTopologySuite, if I reverse the order of all the values it actually gives me the same result (but also reversed)

Comment: So you get an error message if you change the second value saying "Latitude values must be..." but you still think that SQL Server wants Latitude first?

Comment: The next problem stems from the fact that NetTopologySuite (especially given it's happy with values over 90 in both positions) appears to be working with flat 2-D geometry, not 3-D geography, so they still won't produce identical results.

Comment: Woops, that was a mistake in the text in the question, not in the code. The code does use latitude as the second value

Comment: Are there any C# alternatives that that does work with 3-D geography? Or is Microsoft.SqlServer.Types the only option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that NetTopologySuite only performs planar 2d geometry operations.

SqlServer's `geography` type performs geodesic operations within computation of distances and/or other spatial operations.

If you use SqlServer's `geometry` type you should be getting -more or less- the same results.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this, I suspected this was the reason. Do you know of any other way to performs geodesic operations in .Net without using SqlServers geometry type? The reason I'm asking is because Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is not corss-platform

Comment: No, I don't know of any libraries that work like that.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

The question is still not very clear, using SqlServerTypes and SQL server when checking for intersects I get a `MultiLineString` geography type. But question suggests it's a `LineString`

This is what I get both in SQL Server and `SqlServerTypes`

```
MULTILINESTRING ((2.349014 48.864716, -19.99999999999997 52.21038270929611), (-39.99999999999993 51.451383473748834, -73.935242 40.73061))
```

*Reversing the Polygon in SQL.*

The original Polygon seems wrong to me, as in the Question OP says it's a Polygon in the Atlantic Ocean - but in fact it is a Polygon covering the entire Earth except a Polygon in the Atlantic Ocean.

```
DECLARE @polygon geography, @rvrPolygon geography;  
SET @polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-40 60, -20 60, -20 30, -40 30, -40 60))', 4326);  
SET @rvrPolygon = @polygon.ReorientObject()

DECLARE @lineString geography;
SET @lineString = geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-73.935242 40.730610, 2.349014 48.864716)', 4326);  

Select 
    rvrPol = @rvrPolygon,
    --@polygon.ToString(), 
    --@lineString.ToString(), 
    polygon = @polygon, 
    linestring = @lineString, 
    Intersections = @polygon.STIntersection(@lineString).ToString(),
    IntersectsRvrPoly = @rvrPolygon.STIntersection(@lineString).ToString()
```

Without reversing the Polygon it gives me (matches the SqlServerTypes):

```
MULTILINESTRING ((2.349014 48.864716, -19.999999999999972 52.210382709296113), (-39.999999999999929 51.451383473748834, -73.935242 40.73061))
```

With the reverse polygon it gives me:

```
LINESTRING (-19.999999999999972 52.210382709296113, -39.999999999999929 51.451383473748834)
```

Without the correct data and steps to replicate it's impossible to replicate in NetTopolgy to come to a conclusion as to if this is an actual bug, data issue or config issue.

---

Both of your WKTs are different, not sure why you are expecting the same results when the test cases are not identical.

If you fire up SQL Management Studio and Run the following Query you will understand how and why they are different.

```
DECLARE @polygon geography;  
SET @polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-40 60, -20 60, -20 30, -40 30, -40 60))', 4326);  

DECLARE @lineString geography;
SET @lineString = geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING(-73.935242 40.730610, 2.349014 48.864716)', 4326);  


DECLARE @polygon1 geography;  
SET @polygon1 = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((60 -40, 60 -20, 30 -20, 30 -40, 60 -40))', 4326);  

DECLARE @lineString1 geography;
SET @lineString1 = geography::STLineFromText('LINESTRING (40.730610 -73.935242, 48.864716 2.349014)', 4326);  


Select 
    @polygon.ToString(), 
    @lineString.ToString(), 
    p = @polygon, 
    l = @lineString, 
    Intt = @polygon.STIntersection(@lineString),
    Intersections = @polygon.STIntersection(@lineString).ToString()
UNION ALL
Select 
    @polygon1.ToString(), 
    @lineString1.ToString(), 
    p = @polygon1, 
    l = @lineString1, 
    Intt = @polygon1.STIntersection(@lineString1),
    Intersections = @polygon1.STIntersection(@lineString1).ToString()
```

If you analyze the Spatial Results Tab and select the p columns.

[image]

`@polygon` is all the green section except the one I've crossed out. So that will be the entire world except that particular Polygon.
`@polygon1` is the orange polygon - I've highlighted in Red.

Similarly the LineStrings are different aswell.

[image]

So obviously their intersections will be different.One is a line string, the other is a Multi-Line string.

[image]

WKT is a global standard and should be the same for both NetTopology, SQL, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types etc. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry)

If you have another example where the WKTs are identical and still the result is not correct happy to take a look and update the answer, but at this point of time the test cases are not identical.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply @Dawood, really appreciate it! I edited my question to include a test with NetTopologySuit with the exact same WKT as I used with Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Comment: @Q-bertsuit I updated my answer with some more information, but I'm still not sure how to replicate this in NetTopolgy. I tried reversing the polygon to fix the polygon to be an actual polygon instead of the entire world but still I can't replicate it in NetTopology

Comment: Thanks again, so what am I doing wrong so that I get the reverse polygon of what I'm expecting? The line and polygon is just chosen to make sure that that the line stretches a large part of the Earth and that the polygon is in it's way. I'm really looking for any example showing that a very long line gives the same results when intersecting with a polygon in both NetTopology and SqlSerer.Types

Comment: Well you have to make sure the Polygon is Valid and a correct example first, that means the points should be Counter Clockwise order, and explanation can be found here (it's in GeoJson but the same concept follows): https://bertwagner.com/posts/inverted-polygons-how-to-troubleshoot-sql-servers-left-hand-rule/
Once you have defined a correct Polygon, you can test that all out in SQL Mgt studio as shown in my answer.
Then run the same Polygon in Sql, NetTopology and SqlServerTypes and compare the results.

Comment: Once you have a working example , update the question with all the details (same as I have done in my answer) then we can compare and check. If the results are not identical and confirmed we have tried everything, then can raise an issue in Github with all these details - one of the library maintainers will definitely have a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with your suggestions

Comment: I did not try plotting using Sql Mgt studio like you suggested though since I dont have it installed on this machine

Comment: @Q-bertsuit this is interesting, I would suggest posting this in the Github repository as an issue and see if you get a response. Post the link of the issue here aswell please.